# How to obtain distinct values from a column?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have this simple table modeling a person:

```
ID   |   AGE   |   NAME   |
---------------------------
1    |   40    |   Peter  |
---------------------------
2    |   39    |   John   |
---------------------------
3    |   40    |   Lora   |
---------------------------
4    |   40    |   Mark   |
---------------------------
5    |   38    |   Anna   |
---------------------------
```

I want a method that returns a list of integers containing the different ages with no repetition, in this case, the result would be [38,39,40].

I have:

```java
List<Integer> findDistinctAge();
```

but it does not work. I know that I can use `@Query` annotation above the method signature specifying the query on the table. But I don't want to use it, I want to use the JPA syntax, so the name of the method defines the query.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
`List<person> findDistinctAge();`
```

should work. Otherwise do post up your full code.

Comment: "I want a method that returns a list of integers containing the different ages with no repetition" this returns list of `Person`, not `Integer`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "By" in your method name, this will return you Person list with distinct age:

`List<person> findDistinctByAge();`

You can use `person.age` parameter in your further calls or create new list from person list.
I don't think a direct method is available to return Age list.

Comment: Updated my answer for return type and usage.

Comment: I agree and thats why it is mentioned that you will need to iterate on Person object later. BTW, Did you try findDistinctAge ? Does this returns list of age ? it did not work for me and I did not find inbuilt method to return Age list directly.

Answer (score 0):

With [Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces) you can try the trick:

```java
public interface OnlyAge {
    Integer getAge();
}
```

```java
List<OnlyAge> findDistinctBy();
```